# Have MySQL Create Database when Restoring Backup

Tags: mysql

I want to provide users with a backup of an initial database, and give a one-line command to create the database on their systems.  Here's how I'm backing up the database:

```
mysqldump -u root -p -B --add-drop-database "myDatabase" > backup.sql
```

Here's my command to restore it:

```
mysql -u root -p -D "myDatabase" < backup.sql
```

Problem is that it fails:

```
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'myDatabase'
```

Here's what the relevant part of the backup file looks like:

```
--
-- Current Database: `myDatabase`
--

/*!40000 DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `myDatabase`*/;

CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `myDatabase` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */;

USE `myDatabase`;
```

If I type this in inside MySQL, I get no problem.

(I would also like for `mysqldump` to take the comments off dropping the database if it exists, and creating it if it does not exist.)

If it matters, I'm running

```
  MySQL 5.5.49-0ubuntu0.12.04.1.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, you give the SCHEMA NAME in the mysql command. So mysql want to change first the schema to myDatabase AND CANT THAT DO. there is no schema myDatabase. remove the -D option like:

```
mysql -u root -p  < backup.sql
```